# How to detect a word of words that are wrapped by <Text> component in React Native

Tags: react-native, cpu-word, long-press

I have a quick question about the user's long press action that hits the specific word and shows the meaning of words by requesting api to a dictionary service.

The below is the current way the app renders the components. Because the app has to load many words at the same time, I was not able to wrap all words with  each because it drastically slows down the app.

I want This Wordthis word to be reactive to long press.

```
<View>
<Text>I want <Text>This Word</Text>this word to be reactive to long press.</Text>
</View>

<View>
<Text>I want <Text>This Word</Text>this word to be reactive to long press.</Text>
</View>
```

We can't not destroy the current form of the rendering. But if there is a way to destroy it temporarily and recover it after query (dictionary api), then that will be also fascinating.

Please share any ideas with me please!